# Group an array of dictionaries in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following array:

```
array = [
    {'id': 1, 'value1': 'value', 'value2': 'another value'},
    {'id': 1, 'value1': 'value', 'value2': 'another value'},
    {'id': 2, 'value1': 'value', 'value2': 'another value'},
    {'id': 2, 'value1': 'value', 'value2': 'another value'},
]
```

And I want to obtain the following dictionary:

```
expected = {
  '1': [{'value1': 'value', 'value2': 'another value'}, {'value1': 'value', 'value2': 'another value'}],
  '2': [{'value1': 'value', 'value2': 'another value'}, {'value1': 'value', 'value2': 'another value'}]
}
```

Is there a pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Obligatory question: Why Python 2.7?

Comment: legacy system :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can try:

```
array = [
    {'id': 1, 'value1': 'value', 'value2': 'another value'},
    {'id': 1, 'value1': 'value', 'value2': 'another value'},
    {'id': 2, 'value1': 'value', 'value2': 'another value'},
    {'id': 2, 'value1': 'value', 'value2': 'another value'},
]
expected = {}
for value in array:
    dict_id = value["id"]
    temp_dict = dict(value)
    del temp_dict["id"]
    if str(dict_id) in expected:
        expected[str(dict_id)].append(temp_dict)
    else:
        expected[str(dict_id)] = [temp_dict]
print(expected)
```

**Output:**

```
{'1': [{'value1': 'value', 'value2': 'another value'}, {'value1': 'value', 'value2': 'another value'}], '2': [{'value1': 'value', 'value2': 'another value'}, {'value1': 'value', 'value2': 'another value'}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

So what will happen is that you will go through the array like this:

```
array = []
expected = {}
for i in array:
```

and then after that, you will be going to get each of the ids of the dictionaries, and if the id is not in the keys in the expected array, then create it.

```
    if i['id'] not in list(expected.keys()):
        expected[i['id']] = [i]
    else:
        expected[i['id']] += i
```

So this will most likely work in Python 3, not so sure in Python 2.
But hope it helps!

Edit: I think you can remove the ID from the dictionary through `del i['id']`

Comment: This includes the 'id' key in the output dicts, but should otherwise be fine in Python 2.7.